# How to get new transaction hash after user speed up the transaction

Tags: blockchain, hash

## Hello Everyone

When a transaction starts and finishes we are able to get the information via getTransactionReceipt and the other functions that provided with web3.

When a user speeds up the transaction, new transaction starts but we do not know this hash.

How to get the new transaction hash?

Comment: Have you found the solution for this ? I am also having same issue